# openstack dashboard login error in devstack method

Tags: openstack, devstack

when i log into the dashboard of openstack cloud in ubuntu 12.04 it got logged in first but after i reboot the machine it could not log in returns an error " an error occurred while authenicating try again later" .I tried the steps of devstack multi node openstack cloud.

Comment: If you are using memcached service from the environment setup for openstack, you need to restart it by: **sudo service memcached restart**

Answer (score 3):

Devstack does not start all services automatically on startup. 
You can run rejoin-stack.sh to re-run the devstack processes.

You can also run devstack's stack.sh script to restart it. Things will go much quicker this time as all of the files are already available, but you will lose any previous settings (images, key pairs, security groups...)

Comment: ok i ran stack.sh but got error....your already running stack session.... but i destroyed it by unstack.sh.....i did all in virtualbox under root...tell me how to proceed and recover my openstack cloud

Comment: CORRECTION: use rejoin-stack.sh to rerun the devstack!

Comment: @Barak please update your answer with `rejoin-stack.sh`, the question was really about re-joining.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to user 1574095:

After reboot, login as root and access the directory devstack in stack users home directory. Run the stack rejoin script. It will enable the previous screen. At this point all services are running and you can login to horizon